# Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object, abi undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, blockchain, solidity

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const { abi, evm } = require('./compile');
console.log('abi',abi);

provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  'repeat place announce visit level double connect forest lens casual marble ladder',
  'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/6f9868010c6948b2acd01733b944fcac'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({ data: evm.bytecode.object})
    .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

  console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
  provider.engine.stop();
};
deploy();
```

**Compile.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solcCompile.js = require('solc');

const contractPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, 'utf8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
      'Lottery.sol': {
        content: source
      }
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        '*': {
          '*': ['*']
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
  var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
  console.log("THe output", output);
  var contract = output.contracts['Lottery.sol'].Lottery;
  //console.log("Contract", contract)
  var bytecode = contract.evm.bytecode.object;
  var interface = contract.abi;
  module.exports = {interface, bytecode};
```

I created this code and ran the node deploy.js command and it gave me this error "Error: You must provide the JSON interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object."

And it shows me **abi undefined** I didn't understand me how to solve this error.

Comment: can you share the code in `compile.js`

Answer (score 0):

abi is a json file, so you need to add the assert type when requiring or importing it

```js
import { abi, evm } from "url" assert { type: "json" };
```

to use require, have a look at this https://andersonmmi.medium.com/using-require-to-import-abi-data-into-web3-eth-contract-a84d4a5b3cc3